# Finding base path of URL's in item src

Tags: php, html

I need to search for

```
src="http://www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/6a00e54fa8abf788330147e0622c2e970b-800wi.jpg"
```

and get

```
"http://www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/"
```

Since I never know how long the string is I need to get everything up to the last `/`

Comment: I apologize, what is hard for me is actually searching for the content of what is inside SRC="" and getting the link in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at [`pathinfo()`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

ETA due to question edit:

@Chris: what you're trying to do is parse the DOM and pull out the values of src attributes.  The easiest and most foolproof way to do this is to use a DOM parser. Have a look at [`DomDocument::loadHTML`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) and the rest of the `DOMDocument` class.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`stripos()`](http://www.php.net/stripos)

```
$val = substr($url, 0, stripos($url, '/'));
```

Comment: Yet another elegant solution. Well done, jackbot, you are a scholar and a gentleman.

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
$str = 'src="http://www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/6a00e54fa8abf788330147e0622c2e970b-800wi.jpg"';
$str = substr($str,5);
$str = substr($str,0,-1);
echo dirname($str)."/";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop the string in reverse and look for the 1st '\' that you encounter, mark it's position, then copy the string up to that point into another string.

```
$resulted_path = "";    
for($i = strlen($str)-1 ; ($i>=0) && ($str{$i} != '/') ; $i --);
strncpy($resulted_path, $str, $i);
```

Do not forget the ';' after the for loop.
The resulting string should contain your desired string.

References:
[charAt](http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/charat-in-php-150193.html) |
[strncpy](http://phpunixman.sourceforge.net/index.php/man/strncpy/3) |
[strlen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)

Comment: I don't think PHP has a `strncpy` function.